# JAVA Download Multiple Files Servlet Response

Tags: java, file, servlets

I have a Servlet and I am writing stuff in a file.
But I need 1 file for 1 data.

I am doing:

```
 resp.setContentType("application/x-download");
 resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));

 /* SOME STUFF */

 resp.getWriter().println(data);
```

BUT I have a "for" loop.

So I would like that at the end of each loop, it download 1 different file:

```
for (int cpt = 0; cpt < listData.size(); cpt ++){

 resp.setContentType("application/x-download");
 resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));

 resp.getWriter().println(listData.get(i));
 /* THEN DOWNLOAD FILE and i++ */
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not use an API to compress into a `.zip` and download that?

Comment: Thanks! It is just text files. So I need to download them one by one.

Comment: You obviously can't do this. One instance of the servlet can only return one set of headers. Nor would you want servers to be able to do this. Could you imagine getting stuck on a webpage that keeps trying to push files to you?  Annoying.

Comment: take a look at this url : https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/downloading-multiple-files-using-multipart-response/